# ISubscriber, .Subscribe() and .Unsubscribe() scope

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to understand the scoping of using SE.Redis objects specifically in the area of subscribing for (and unsubscribing) to notifications.

I'd like to do something like the following to wait for a remote node to indicate it has changed/freed a resource (a very dumb distributed semaphore):

```
var t = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
sub.Subscribe(key, (c, v) =>
{
    t.TrySetResult(true);
    sub.UnsubscribeAll();
});
return t.Task;
```

I am fairly certain that is wrong :) and in a multithreaded environment with the `ConnectionMultiplexer` shared I'm probably going to end up in a race where one thread subscribes to a particular `RedisChannel` whilst another unsubscribes from it.

Is it possible to safely/efficiently implement this pattern or am I trying to simplify this problem too much and need a per process 'subscription manager' to coordinate my subscriptions?

Comment: That is an interesting use-case; I'm not sure I could offer any strict guarantees around how that will behave, though - I'd be quite reluctant to do it that way, to be honest.

Comment: Any thoughts as to how you might implement a semaphore then? I'm still struggling a bit to understand the scope of the subscriptions as well - not sure if that is a generic redis thing or if SE.Redis changes the game on that at all?